# Get coordinate from path with multiple points based on fraction of path's distance

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have an array where every array value is an object `{ lat: ___, lng: ___ }`. I'd like to input a fraction (let's say `20%` (`0.2`)) and get the specific coordinate for that fraction, based on the distance from point 0. What this means that given the distance `d` (sum of all individual paths between points), the coordinate should be 1/5 of `d`. If I were to set the fraction to `0` this would give me the first coordinates in the path. And if I were to set the fraction to `1` it'd give me the last.

I've read up on coordinates based on fractions here on SO ([Calculate point between two coordinates based on a percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907276/calculate-point-between-two-coordinates-based-on-a-percentage)) and used this function in my algorithm.

What I figured I might do is add all paths between each point together to get a sum `d`. Then for every distance between points `f` I'd check to see if this distance were lower than `d`. If `true`, deduct `f` from `d`. If `false`, use the function from the link above and input the remaining fraction `d`. I thought this'd give me the correct coordinate.

This works to some extent but for individuals paths with a long distance it leaves gaps throughout the full path. [image: Image showing gaps between certain points. It's not a consistent flow of markers]

Here's the code for the algorithm as well as the code for generating this picture. I think the problem occurs in `modules.fractionCoordinateArray`.

```js
var modules = {};

modules.distance = function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, km = true) {
  var p = 0.017453292519943295,
    c = Math.cos;
  var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 + c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;

  if (km) {
    return 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km
  } else {
    return 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)) * 1000; // meters
  }
};

modules.distanceSum = function(arr, km = true) {
  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      total += modules.distance(arr[i - 1].lat, arr[i - 1].lng, arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng, km);
    }
  }

  return total;
};

modules.fractionCoordinateArray = function(arr, frac = 0) {
  var dist = modules.distanceSum(arr),
    fractions = [];

  if (frac <= 0) {
    return {
      lat: arr[0].lat,
      lng: arr[0].lng
    };
  } else if (frac >= 1) {
    return {
      lat: arr[arr.length - 1].lat,
      lng: arr[arr.length - 1].lng
    };
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      var frc = modules.distance(arr[i - 1].lat, arr[i - 1].lng, arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng) / dist;

      if (frac > frc) {
        frac -= frc;
      } else {
        return modules.fractionCoordinate(arr[i - 1].lat, arr[i - 1].lng, arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng, frac);
      }
    }
  }
};

modules.fractionCoordinate = function(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, per) {
  return {
    lat: lat1 + (lat2 - lat1) * per,
    lng: lng1 + (lng2 - lng1) * per
  };
};

/*
 For generating the image I used this;
*/
var dst = [],
  path = [{
    lat: 12,
    lng: 12
  }, {
    lat: 13.75,
    lng: 13
  }, {
    lat: 14,
    lng: 17
  }, {
    lat: 59,
    lng: 18
  }]; // Example path
  
for (var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
  var crd = modules.fractionCoordinateArray(path, i / 50);
  dst.push('markers=size:tiny%7C' + crd.lat + ',' + crd.lng);
}
console.log('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?autoscale=2&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&' + dst.join('&'));
```

I'm looking for help on how to solve this problem in the most efficient way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in `fractionCoordinateArray()` would be more or less correct if you first converted the fraction `frac` into an absolute distance `totalDistRemaining` (by multiplying it by the total path distance), and then worked with (i.e., subtracted individual edge lengths off) that from that point on.

Then when you call

```
return modules.fractionCoordinate(arr[i-1].lat, arr[i-1].lng, arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng, frac);
```

you should instead pass

`totalDistRemaining / distance(arr[i-1].lat, arr[i-1].lng, arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng)`

as the last parameter.

Finally, to improve speed, you could add a third entry to each array element that records the total distance along the path so far (so this will be 0 at the start, and equal to the total path length at the end).  This values will be nondecreasing, so you can now find the path segment containing any given path distance in O(log n) time with binary search.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I updated the code and put it inside a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magnusburton/v1s9qLmy/) and it works great. It's just a minor gap in the top part of the path now. Mind taking a look?

Also, I didn't quite understand the last part on how to improve speed. I added a distance entry to every array element in the fiddle and for every element it's increasing. Now, what am I supposed to use binary search for?

Comment: @MagnusBurton: Glad it's mostly working for you.  It's possible you have an off-by-one error -- the best way to debug these is to try smaller cases (e.g. length-2 arrays) and see if you can isolate it.  Regarding binary search: If there are, say, 100 edges, you first look at the total-distance-so-far entry of the 50th; if this is already above your target distance, you know it has to be somewhere in the first 50, so you would then look at the 25th entry; if this was below your target distance, you would then look at the 37th (roughly half-way between 25 and 50), etc.

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong and I kept deleting the wrong value in my loop. It's fixed now. Thank you for your explanation of binary search. Will implement that now because that seems like a great speed improvement.

Comment: You're welcome :)  Binary search should give a big speedup for long (many-edge) paths.